# vt tools decompose - median_DP

Tags: datatable, data-manipulation, vcf-variant-call-format

I have a table of Chr, pos, ref, alt, DP median that was once multiallelic but converted using vt decompose to biallelic. However, the DP median does not become biallelic even with the -s flag. Leaving me with a table as such:

| Position info | median DP |
| --- | --- |
| 3 CHR3 POS1 A G | 1,1,2 |
| 3 CHR3 POS1 A C | 1,1,2 |
| 3 CHR3 POS1 A T | 1,1,2 |
| 5 CHR3 POS2 C AT | 10,19,4,2.5,25 |
| 5 CHR3 POS2 C T | 10,19,4,2.5,25 |
| 5 CHR3 POS2 C AGT | 10,19,4,2.5,25 |
| 5 CHR3 POS2 C CG | 10,19,4,2.5,25 |
| 5 CHR3 POS2 C G | 10,19,4,2.5,25 |

I need to find a way to take the first 5 columns and then the corresponding number from the 6th column:

| Position Info | median DP |
| --- | --- |
| 3 CHR3 POS1 A G | 1 |
| 3 CHR3 POS1 A C | 1 |
| 3 CHR3 POS1 A T | 2 |
| 5 CHR3 POS2 C AT | 10 |
| 5 CHR3 POS2 C T | 19 |
| 5 CHR3 POS2 C AGT | 4 |
| 5 CHR3 POS2 C CG | 2.5 |
| 5 CHR3 POS2 C G | 25 |

For some reason I just can't wrap my head around a method. The number in the first column is the amount of variants at that position and runs all the way up to 46 in my data. I tried using an awk command but realised I needed to write a lot and that there must be a much easier way I haven't thought of.

Many thanks for any help anyone can provide.